# Riemann- Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuos and $\phi$ is of bounded variation . Prove that $$\psi=
\int_a^x  fd\phi 
$$ is a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$

**Attempt:** I have this problem, but I can not solve, I hope someone can help me! thank you. I don´t know how i could use Jordan descomposition, but here is my attempt but i am stuck. Let $\Gamma $ be a partition of $[a,b]$ then $$S_\Gamma= \sum_{i=1}^{n} | \phi (x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})| $$ $$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\int_a^{x_i} fd\phi-\int_a^{x_{i-1}} fd\phi|$$  let $\Gamma_1=[a=x_0,x_1,...,x_{m-1},x_m=x_{i-1}]$ be a partition of $[a,x_{i-1}] $and $\Gamma_2= \Gamma_1 \bigcup {x_i}=[a=x_0,x_1,...,x_{m-1},x_m=x_{i-1}, x_{m+1}=x_i]$ so $\Gamma_2 $is a partition of $[a,x_{i}]$, then$$ \int_a^{x_i} fd\phi - \int_a^{x_{i-1}} fd\phi=f(\eta_{m+1})[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})]$$ then $$ S_\Gamma=f(\eta_{m+1})\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})]$$, but $\phi$ is a bounded variation function so $$S_\Gamma \leq f(\eta_{m+1})*M$$ where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the Jordan decomposition.